# CSS to wrap text on whitespace, but still expand container to fit long strings without whitespace

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing text. The div should be at least 100px wide, and should try to restrict itself to 100px by wrapping the text inside on whitespace. However, if there is a single word or number which contains no breaking spaces, and which is extremely long, I want the div to expand to fit that string (i.e. no scrollbars, no cutting the text off on the right, and no allowing the text to extend outside of the div). Finally, the text should be centered within the div.

The only way I know to accomplish this is with `display: table-cell`.

```
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

However, I would like to know whether or not there are alternative methods of achieving this behavior, with pure CSS, but without using CSS tables.

```css
.container {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  asd asd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdasdasdasdasd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd </div>
```

Comment: I tryed and can't find another way right now (in CSS). Why don't you want it to be a table-cell?

Comment: and would it be ok to you to add more HTML-Elements?

Comment: Why not just use `display: table`, rather `table-cell`?

Comment: Adding more elements is fine. I just want some options in case table cells don't play well with the rest of my styles layer.

Answer (score 2):

Try **Flexbox**

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/myajoqbc/3/)

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 100px;
}

 .inner {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>loooooooooooooooooooooooong Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, eum, sapiente. Deserunt, laboriosam accusamus s beatae tenetur illo, provident vel explicabo. Tenetur, eligendi, facere. Voluptas nostrum incidunt, sit maxime magnam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach appears to work in Chrome, but not in IE. Nonetheless, these are the types of things I was hoping to see.

Comment: I'm using IE version 11.0.9600.18125. When I run your code snippet or view your Fiddle, the loo...oong word overflows the inner div, and so isn't centered with respect to the rest of the text.